# Удаление сразу нескольких элементов из коллекции по индеку

Tags: c#

Есть коллекция:

```
List<string> str_list = new List<string>();
str_list.Add("string1");
str_list.Add("string1");
str_list.Add("string2");
str_list.Add("string3");
str_list.Add("string2");
```

Необходимо удалить элементы под индексами: `str_list[1]` и `str_list[3]`.

Конечно, знаю что у коллекции есть метод `RemoveAt`, но ведь с ним нельзя сделать так:

```
str_list.RemoveAt(1);
str_list.RemoveAt(3);
```

Т.к. после выполнения `str_list.RemoveAt(1)` [3] будет уже [2].

По значению нельзя, так они могут повторятся.

Можно ли, как-то сразу задать диапазон удаления элементов по индексу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас есть сплошной диапазон индексов `[a, b]`, делайте так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < b - a + 1; i++)
    coll.RemoveAt(a);
```

Если у вас есть несплошной список индексов, отсортируйте их по убыванию:

```
foreach (var idx in indices.OrderByDescending(i => i))
    call.RemoveAt(idx);
```

Если индексы могут повторяться, добавьте `Distinct`: `indices.Distinct().OrderByDescending(i => i)`.

Встроенного метода, насколько мне известно, нету.

Comment: а во втором примере не foreach должен быть?

Comment: @Grundy: И правда, исправил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
str_list.RemoveAt("string1");
```

Если не ошибаюсь

Comment: *"По значению нельзя, так они могут повторятся."*

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?